# elastic search - exclude documents matching criteria

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to search and exclude certain documents?

my use case is that I serve 5 documents to the client at a time, and I want to allow the client to query for more.

the idea is to store IDs of documents client already has and pass this back to the API endpoint.

I want to apply a search terms and also exclude documents that match the sent IDs.

Comment: you might want to use scroll API.

Comment: Scroll API is more suited for using over a _large_ result set. I would take a look at `size` and `from` parameters to implement pagination

Comment: Assuming that your search results are ordered by some criterion (timestamp, score, ...), that is